# Find all solutions to the Diophantine equation $2x+3y =1$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How to find all the solutions to the Diophantine equation $2x+3y =1$. My professor didn't explain to us how to do this.

Comment: $y$ can't be even, so $y=2k+1$. So $x=-3k-1$.

Comment: Are there any steps you used in between this to get y = 2k +1 and x = -3k -1?

Comment: If $y$ is not even it must be odd, so $y=2k+1$ for some integer $k$. Substituting in the original equation and solving for $x$, we get $x=-3k-1$. vonbrand's solution is equivalent, just set $\text{my k}=-\text{his k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Bezóut's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), if $\gcd(a, b) = m$, there exist integers $u$, $v$ such that $u a + v b = m$. Given this solution, all others are given by $(u + k b / m, v - k a / m)$ for some $k$ an integer.

In your case, one obvious solution is $x = -1$, $y = 1$, all solutions are then $x = -1 + 3 k$ and $y = 1 - 2 k$.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful.